# eBay Python SDK 'findItemsAdvanced' call returns Internal Server Error

Tags: python, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am trying to use the following wrapper for the ebay api:
http://code.google.com/p/ebay-sdk-python/

However, when I execute the following code I obtain:

```
from ebaysdk import finding, tag, nodeText

f = finding()
f.execute('findItemsAdvanced', tag('keywords', 'shoes'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unix/dfernand/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebaysdk-0.1.6-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/__init__.py", line 141, in execute
    self._response_content = self._execute_http_request()
  File "/home/unix/dfernand/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebaysdk-0.1.6-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/__init__.py", line 244, in _execute_http_request
    raise Exception("%s" % e)
Exception: Internal Server Error
```

Then try to get more info but nothing meaningful comes up:

```
error = f.error()
print error
findItemsAdvanced error:
Exception: Internal Server Error
```

I am not sure where the error is coming from - I tried copying the [yaml file](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/ebay.yaml) to the location the egg file for the module is installed (i.e., /home/unix/dfernand/bin/lib/python2.7/site-packages/), and nothing changes.

I filled in the yaml file with the Sandbox keys, then tried to filled it in with the Production Keys, then I changed the name to match the name in my ebay developers account, etc.  Nothing works.  I am quite clueless on what's going on.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Example of my yaml file:

```
    # ebaysdk API Configurations

name: Key Set 1 #(note: here i changed it to Key Set 1, name in ebay website from ebay_api_config)

# Trading - External
api.ebay.com:
    password: _password_
    username: _username_
    appid: myproduction-appid-fromdeveloperssite
    certid: _certid_
    devid: _devid_
    token:
    version: 671
    https: 1

# Shopping
open.api.ebay.com:
    appid: myproduction-appid-fromdeveloperssite
    certid: myproduction-certid-fromdeveloperssite
    devid: myproduction-devid-fromdeveloperssite
    version: 671

# Finding/Merchandising
svcs.ebay.com:
    appid: myprodction-appid-fromdeveloperssite
    version: 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest version. I've added a lot of error handling that will help.

https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python

```
from ebaysdk import finding

api = finding(appid='YOUR_APPID_HERE', debug=True)
api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {'keywords': 'shoes'})

print api.response_dict()
```

Adding debug=True will dump the http request/response. If you're still having troubles, pass along the request/response.